# How to add curson style "not-allowed" to Material UI datagrid disabled row?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I've a conditional disabled row in material ui data grid where user cannot select or perform actions on it.
I want to show `cursor: "not-allowed"` on this row. How can we add styling to that row? As we don't have any parameter in rows specifying that it's a disabled row.

```
      <DataGrid
        rowHeight={75}
        components={{
          NoRowsOverlay: CustomNoRowsOverlay,
        }}
        onSelectionModelChange={currentlySelected}
        selectionModel={[...selected]}
        columns={columns}
        rows={rows}
        autoHeight
        disableSelectionOnClick={disableSelectionOnClick}
        {...props}
        checkboxSelection={role === ROLES.ADMIN}
        disableColumnMenu
        isRowSelectable={(params) =>
          !(params?.row?.id === currentUserID)
        }
      />
```

and This is what disabled row and normal row look like in browser inspect element. First one is disabled row here.
[image]

CSS implementation for root class, in which the datagrid is wrapped.

```
root: {
  '& .MuiDataGrid-columnsContainer': {
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.secondary.main,
    color: theme.palette.text.light,
    lineHeight: '62px !important',
    maxHeight: '62px !important',
    minHeight: '62px !important',

    '& .MuiCheckbox-root': {
      color: theme.palette.checkbox.secondary,
    },
  },
  '& .MuiDataGrid-cell, & .MuiDataGrid-columnHeader': {
    outline: 'none !important',
  },
  '& .MuiDataGrid-window': {
    backgroundColor: colors.bgColor.secondary,
  },
  '& .MuiDataGrid-columnSeparator': { display: 'none' },
  '
  '& .MuiCheckbox-root': {
    color: theme.palette.checkbox.main,
  },
  '& .MuiDataGrid-sortIcon': {
    color: theme.palette.iconColor.default,
  },
  '& .MuiCheckbox-colorPrimary.Mui-disabled': {
    color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26)',
  },
},
```

Comment: @DrewReese it's simply using root class on top on it, and there is nothing related to specially the disabled styling.

Answer (score -1):

Apply your own custom css styles and import it to your component :

```
import './custom.css'
```

```
.MuiCheckbox-colorPrimary.Mui-disabled {
  cursor: not-allowed !important;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work. Plus you're telling solution for only checkbox. I need to show not-allowed cursor on whole row